# Who is the disapproving hobbit?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, movie, character-identification

During one of *The Lord of the Rings* films I have a memory of a very curmudgeonly old hobbit, sweeping his porch or walk, I think, as he looks disapprovingly at some of the protagonists going down the road by his house.

#### Who is this old hobbit?

#### Does he have a part in the books?

Comment: I believe this question is equally appropriate on both sites.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### [Everard Proudfoot](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Everard_Proudfoot)

If the old man you're talking about is the one pictured below, that [Noel Appelby](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0032370/). He's credited as Everard Proudfoot on [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120737/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast)

[image: Grumpy old man]

The only one mention of an Everard in the Lord of the Rings and it is one Everard Took, so unfortunately this character does not feature in the books.

> Master **Everard Took** and Miss Melilot Brandybuck got on a table and with bells in their hands began to dance the Springle-ring: a pretty dance, but rather vigorous.

It may be worth noting that originally his name was Prospero Took that was later changed to Everard

> The young Took who danced on the table changes his name from Prospero to Everard

It would seem that although this first scene of the character is invented, the later on of our friendly Everard Proudfoot stamping his feet (as noted in [@NKCampbell](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/55637/nkcampbell)'s [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/166027/)) is in fact based on old Odo Proudfoot. Who is in fact Frodo's maternal Grandmother's aunt's son.

As per the request from OP below is the footage from which I took the screencap:

Comment: This image is perfect. Exactly as I saw myself looking out the window of my favorite Wicker Park burger place while the chaos of the street festival is happening outside.

Comment: He does in fact smile later.

Comment: Ahem...Proud feet! Also, is I think bad that I thought this was a woman all these years?

Comment: Umm most likely, considering his wife comes up behind him!

Comment: I always thought that was 'her' friend or relative. After all, she does appear to be quite a bit younger.

Comment: Ah possibly! Everard must just be doing well for himself!

Answer (score 23):

**Odo Proudfoot**

In the book, the character is named Odo Proudfoot, and the scene at Bilbo's party is very similar to the book. Why they would invent a new name when this film character does exactly the same things as the book character is odd.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 15):

### Everard Proudfoot

[image]

He is a Hobbit invented for the films and is played by [Noel Appleby](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0032370/).

I believe this is the scene that you are referring to:

> Mr. Proudfoot was a grumpy old gaffer, who minded his own business and
>   tended his garden. However, he enjoyed Gandalf's fireworks and only
>   expressed his disapproval when his wife arrived. He was present at
>   Bilbo's Farewell Party. He later met the four hobbits as they returned
>   home from their journey.
>   <sub>[Everard Proudfoot](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Everard_Proudfoot)</sub>

While credited in the film as "Everard Proudfoot" it does seem that this character was based on Odo Proudfoot from the books.

Comment: Was I really the only one to think this was Farmer Maggot?

Comment: lol - @Voronwë-  probably - Farmer Magott didn't live in Hobbiton ;)

Comment: @Voronwë I probably have the latest answer because I spent about five minutes looking at the actor of Farmer Maggot and The photo below side by side trying to compare them.